# How to zip a folder?

Tags: vba

I'm writing a macro, for any application using VBA, to zip or compress a folder.

```vb
Sub test1()
Dim source, zipfile as String 
source = "C:\TempZip\FolderTest\"
zipfile = "C:\TempZip\NameOFZip.zip"
CreateZipFile source, zipfile
End Sub

Sub CreateZipFile(folderToZipPath As Variant, zippedFileFullName As Variant)
Dim ShellApp As Object

'Create an empty zip file
Open zippedFileFullName For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1

'Copy the files & folders into the zip file
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items

Do Until ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items.Count = ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items.Count
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
End Sub
```

It creates the zip file, but the size is 1K, which means it is empty.

When I try to open it, I get

> "windows Cannot open the Folder, it is invalid"

Comment: Why does it matter if your macro is embedded in an Excel document or not?

Comment: when I do search on google or here all the answered for excel, mostly when you talk about VBA, the people assumed the macro is for excel or for microsoft, so I didn't want the answer to be using excel's functions

Answer (score 1):

Your code itself does not have a problem. The 'problem' is that Windows (standard UAC) does not allow creating/moving such files on a custom folder created on SO drive. It allow that only for some 'authorized' folders (Temp, Documents etc.). You can also try playing with folder security settings (taking the ownership, things like that...). And VBA does not raise an elocvent error warning.

Try, please replacing of

```
 zipfile = "C:\TempZip\NameOFZip.zip"
```

with

```
  zipfile = Environ("TEMP") & "\NameOFZip.zip"
```

Then, search the archive in: `"C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\"`. It will contain the folder files...

Edited: I can confirm that taking the ownership of your folder (on C:) and give full control to your Windows user, your code will also work for your initial chosen folder.

Comment: First thanks for the answer, my application didn't define Environ("TEMP"), for the next part, I'm admin on my machin, does that make any fiffrence

Comment: @Amira: Welcome! Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: FaneDuru i did using Environ("TEMP"), but it gives me error cant define it !!!!!!

Comment: Then, try directly using of `zipfile = C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\NameOFZip.zip"`. Take care of changing 'YourUserName` with your real user name... You can also try `zipfile = VBA.Environ("TEMP")`, only to see if the above error is still raised.

Comment: What happens? Changing the path do you obtain the same empty archive? What 'nothing works' does mean? Do you receive an error? If yes, on which line and what error?

Comment: FaneDuru yes it creats the zip file but didn't move the files to it, and when i try to open it or extract it windows gives me error invalid file

Comment: but I did something, I tried to use the same code to copy the files from the source file C:\TempZip\FolderTest\ to another folder C:\TempZip\DISTINATION\, and it worked perfectly.................Then I guess the problem is with the zipfile, and that makes sense, for somereason is invalid so the system cant access it to copy the files to it

Comment: @Amira: Does the code create the zip file **in the Temp folder**, but without zipped files inside? This is what you mean?

Comment: @Amira:  What do you suggest it is invalid? "TempZip" folder name? If yes, I do not think so... I initially tested your code on a path not containing such a name and it did not work. It used to behave exactly like in your case (empty zip file), but when I changed the location in ones I knew Windows allows moving files, it worked. And it started working in the first location only after **I made changes in the folder security settings**. It does not matter that your user is an administrator! You must take the folder ownership and give to the user full access.

Comment: no I mean the zip file itself is invalid, it is empty yes but even I cant open it manually, I tried to folder in my username, I can't change the security setting in the actual working environment.... I will try this code on the server today to see if I get different result.